# Flowlines of blobs

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I have the following formula for blobs/metaballs, which is [said](http://www.geogebra.org/en/upload/files/english/Michael_Horvath/Metaballs/geogebra_metaballs.htm) to be the same as the one used for electromagnetism:
\begin{gather}
f(x,y,z) = \frac{d(A,B)}{\sqrt{(x-xA)^2 + (y-yA)^2 + (z-zA)^2}} \\
g(x,y,z) = \frac{d(C,D)}{\sqrt{(x-xC)^2 + (y-yC)^2 + (z-zC)^2}} \\
h(x,y,z) = f(x,y,z) + g(x,y,z) - \text{Threshold}_1 \\
i(x,y,z) = \min(\text{Threshold}_2, \max(0, h(x,y,z)))
\end{gather}

This produces the equipotential lines that orbit the charges. However, what is the formula for the perpendicular flowlines?

Answer (score 1):

If $h(x,y,z)=C$ (that is, a [level set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set) of $h(x,y,z)$) gives you the equipotential surface, then $\nabla h(x,y,z)=\langle\frac{\partial h}{\partial x},\frac{\partial h}{\partial y},\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}\rangle$ is a vector that gives you the vectorfield perpendicular to the level sets (or, keeping with your electromagnetism analogy, the resulting electric field).

To find the [flow curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Flow_curves) $\gamma(t)$ from a given point, we solve the initial value problem
$$
\gamma(0)=\langle x_0,y_0,z_0\rangle\\
\gamma'(t)= \nabla h(\gamma(t))
$$
Let me know if that's along the lines of what you're looking for, and if you want clarification on that.

---

#### My attempt to clarify:

For the sake of making this as understandable as possible, I will stick to the electromagnetism analogy.  The "flow curve" we want is the trajectory of a point charge under the approximation that it exactly follows the direction of the electric field.

The first step is to find the direction of the electric field (a vector field), given the voltage field
$$
V(x,y,z) = f(x,y,z)+g(x,y,z)
$$
The components of the electric field are given by
$$
E_x=-\frac{\partial V(x,y,z)}{\partial x}\qquad
E_y=-\frac{\partial V(x,y,z)}{\partial y}\qquad
E_z=-\frac{\partial V(x,y,z)}{\partial z}
$$
These are the [partial derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) of $V(x,y,z)$.  We find, for example, that
$$
\begin{align}
E_x &= -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\\
&= -\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)\\
&= -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{k_1}{\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2}} 
-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{k_2}{\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2+(z-z_2)^2}}\\
&=
\end{align}
$$
*editing...*

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand any of that. :(

Comment: Could you put that in f(x,y,z) form?

Comment: Well, before I go into detail, I'd like to get a better idea of what it is that you want. We could probably find the formula that, given a particular point, gives you the flow-curve including that point.  Is this what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure. I want it to look like [this](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/34033). It looks like there are 20 radial "lines" emanating from each charge.

Comment: I can't see the picture, but what we can do is start with a point near the charge, and find the radial line going outward.  Do this $20$ times, and you should have the picture, if I understand correctly.  I'll update my post accordingly (probably tonight).

Comment: Here are some more pictures you may be able to see. http://www.grasshopper3d.com/profiles/blogs/rheotomic-surfaces-and-flowline-generation-tool

Comment: What my ultimate goal is is to be able to plot the intersections of the equipotential lines that orbit the charges and the perpendicular flowlines. Preferably without having to resort to things like marching cubes and other pixel/voxel type deals.